# Creating select combo with option already selected in ReactTS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm dynamically generating a select combobox in ReactTS and just trying to figure out how to set the selected item based on what is in my state/props?

My code so far generates the select box fine, I just do not know how to put the appropriate option as "selected" if it matches the value of "selectedGroupingOption" in my props

My class

```
interface IGroupingProps {
    groupingOptions : string[],
    selectedGroupingOption : string
  }
class GroupingSelector extends React.Component<IGroupingProps, {}> {

      public render() {

       return (
        <div className="Grouping-selector">
            <div className="Horizontal-panel-right Grouping-search-combo">
                <select>
                    {this.props.groupingOptions.map((name, index)=> 
                        <option key={index}>{name}</option>
                    )}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div className="Content Horizontal-panel-right">
                Group by
            </div>            
        </div>);
    }


}

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
    return {
      groupingOptions: state.groupingOptions,
      selectedGroupingOption: state.selectedGroupingOption
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> [React] uses a value attribute on the root select tag. This is more convenient in a controlled component because you only need to update it in one place.  ([source](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#why-select-value))

So to apply this to your code:

```
 <select value={this.props.selectedGroupingOption}>
     {this.props.groupingOptions.map((name, index)=> 
         <option value={name} key={index}>{name}</option>
     )}
 </select>
```